# cleaning up c# code connecting to SQL databse

Tags: c#, sql

I have created a form in visual studio 2019 that allows user to connect to a database I have made in SQL. It allows to find, edit, delete and add to a table named items.

I would simply like help cleaning up this code as it feels very messy and would be very grateful of any pointers to help divide this code up into separate classes and how I would go about doing this.

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace FinalDatabaseConnection
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    //  `if statement dealing with SQL query selection decided through combo box`

    //if statment dealing with sql queries once button hit
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblCompleteItemInfo.Text = ("");
        String source = @"Data Source=WIN10-LAP-HJP\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=VisualStudioConnect;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);
        con.Open();

        if ((string)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Find" && checkBoxPCSearch.Checked)
        {

            String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Items Where PartCode = @SelectedPartCode";

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);

            SetInsertParameters(cmd);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SetResponse(dr);
            AllVisible();

        }

        else if ((string)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Find" && checkBoxNameSearch.Checked)
        {
            checkBoxPCSearch.Checked = false;
            String sqlSelectQuery = "SELECT * FROM Items Where Name = @SelectedName";

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlSelectQuery, con);

            SetInsertParameters(cmd);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            SetResponse(dr);
            AllVisible();
        }


        if ((String)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Add")
        {
            checkBoxNameSearch.Checked = false;
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(
                "INSERT INTO items(Description,Colour,Manufacturer,StockLevel,Name) " +
                "VALUES ( @Description, @Colour, @Manufacturer, @StockLevel,@Name)", con);
            SetInsertParameters(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteReader();

        }
        else if ((string)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Delete")
        {

            var sqlDeleteQuery = "Delete from items where PartCode =  @SelectedPartCode";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlDeleteQuery, con);
            SetInsertParameters(cmd);
            SqlDataReader myreader;
            myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            myreader.Read();
        }
        else if ((string)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Edit")
        {

            var cmd = new SqlCommand("update items SET Description = @Description ,Colour 
= @Colour, Manufacturer = @Manufacturer, StockLevel = @StockLevel, Name = @Name where partcode = @SelectedPartCode", con);

            SetInsertParameters(cmd);
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
    //setting the response for the find function


    private void SetResponse(SqlDataReader dr)
    {

        if (dr.Read())
        {

            string itemDescription = (dr["Description"].ToString());
            txtDescription.Text = (dr["Description"].ToString());

            string itemColour = (dr["Colour"].ToString());
            txtColour.Text = (dr["Colour"].ToString());

            string itemManufacturer = (dr["Manufacturer"].ToString());
            txtManufacturer.Text = (dr["Manufacturer"].ToString());

            string itemStockLevel = (dr["StockLevel"].ToString());
            txtStockLevel.Text = (dr["StockLevel"].ToString());

            string itemName = (dr["Name"].ToString());

            txtName.Text = (dr["Name"].ToString());

            string itemPartCode = (dr["PartCode"].ToString());
            txtPartCode.Text = (dr["PartCode"].ToString());

            lblCompleteItemInfo.Text = ($"The items description is: {itemDescription} " +
                                        $"The items colour is: {itemColour} " +
                                        $"The items Manufacturer is: {itemManufacturer} " +
                                        $"The Items Stock Level is :{itemStockLevel} " +
                                        $"The Items Name is: {itemName} " +
                                        $"The items PartCode is: {itemPartCode} ");
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("error");

        }
    }
    //applying the values for sql queries through the input in tbox
    private void SetInsertParameters(SqlCommand cmd)
    {

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", txtDescription.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Colour", txtColour.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Manufacturer", txtManufacturer.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockLevel", txtStockLevel.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PartCode", txtPartCode.Text);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedPartCode", txtPartCodeEnter.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SelectedName", txtNameEnter.Text);
    }

`method to make all things visible so that it can be customised down for specfic selection in combo box`

                private void AllVisible()
    {
        //txtboxes
        txtDescription.Visible = true;
        txtColour.Visible = true;
        txtManufacturer.Visible = true;
        txtStockLevel.Visible = true;
        txtName.Visible = true;
        txtPartCode.Visible = true;
        txtPartCodeEnter.Visible = true;
        txtNameEnter.Visible = true;
        //lbls  
        lblDescription.Visible = true;
        lblColour.Visible = true;
        lblManufacturer.Visible = true;
        lblStockLevel.Visible = true;
        lblName.Visible = true;
        lblPartCode.Visible = true;
        lblNameEnter.Visible = true;
        lblPartCode.Visible = true;
        checkBoxNameSearch.Visible = true;
        checkBoxPCSearch.Visible = true;
    }
        `Customising what is viewable depending on sql selection`

                private void cbfunctionSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if ((String)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Add")
        {
            AllVisible();

            checkBoxNameSearch.Visible = false;
            checkBoxPCSearch.Visible = false;

            txtPartCodeEnter.Visible = false;
            txtNameEnter.Visible = false;
            txtPartCode.Visible = false;

            lblPartCode.Visible = false;
            lblNameEnter.Visible = false;
            lblPartCode.Visible = false;

            HelpLabel.Text = ("input the details for the item to be added.");
        }
        else if ((String)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Find")
        {
            AllVisible();
            txtDescription.Visible = false;
            txtColour.Visible = false;
            txtManufacturer.Visible = false;
            txtStockLevel.Visible = false;
            txtName.Visible = false;
            txtPartCode.Visible = false;

            lblDescription.Visible = false;
            lblColour.Visible = false;
            lblManufacturer.Visible = false;
            lblStockLevel.Visible = false;
            lblName.Visible = false;
            lblPartCode.Visible = false;

            HelpLabel.Text = ("input the Partcode of the item and the information will be displayed.");

        }
        else if ((String)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Edit")
        {
            AllVisible();
            lblPartCode.Visible = false;
            txtPartCode.Visible = false;
            txtNameEnter.Visible = false;
            lblNameEnter.Visible = false;
            checkBoxNameSearch.Visible = false;
            checkBoxPCSearch.Visible = false;
            HelpLabel.Text = ("Input the partcode of the item you would like to edit. Then the Information.");
        }
        else if ((String)cbfunctionSelection.SelectedItem == "Delete")
        {
            AllVisible();
            txtDescription.Visible = false;
            txtColour.Visible = false;
            txtManufacturer.Visible = false;
            txtStockLevel.Visible = false;
            txtName.Visible = false;
            txtPartCode.Visible = false;
            txtNameEnter.Visible = false;
            checkBoxNameSearch.Visible = false;
            checkBoxPCSearch.Visible = false;

            lblDescription.Visible = false;
            lblColour.Visible = false;
            lblManufacturer.Visible = false;
            lblStockLevel.Visible = false;
            lblName.Visible = false;
            lblPartCode.Visible = false;
            lblNameEnter.Visible = false;
            HelpLabel.Text = ("Input the partcode of the item you would like to delete.");
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnDisplayItemTable.Text = ("Refresh items table");
        //This is database connection string
        String source = @"Data Source=WIN10-LAP-HJP\MSSQLSERVER1;Initial Catalog=VisualStudioConnect;Integrated Security=True";

        //this is defining source as variable "con" to be used for SQL connection
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(source);

        //opens connection
        con.Open();
        // just message box
        MessageBox.Show("connected");

        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Items", source);
        DataTable dtb1 = new DataTable();
        sqlDa.Fill(dtb1);

        dgv1.DataSource = dtb1;
    }

    private void radioButton2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form3().Show();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting this is my first post

Comment: This might be better suited to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You can allways edit questions.

Comment: agree on the "codereview" thing, but my advice: "look at tools like Dapper"

Answer (score 0):

As per ideal OOP You need to move your DB logic to seperate DB helper class rather than 
putting whole sets of logic to code behind of your windows Forms.

e.g. SetInsertParameters is for pure DB operations, which can be in DB helper class.

Form should not be responsible for storing DB Connection string, fetching data from SQL etc...

You can create common method for several common DB operation which will take parameters and will do needful thing like below lines can go as common function in DB helper class

```
SetInsertParameters(cmd);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
SetResponse(dr);
```

Also non DB Helper related common logic can also be part of common function might be in same form code behind or in other helper class.

Your SetResponse method from Helper class should return Modal class with all properties like description, color, Manufacture etc..

So, you can return Modal class with all properties in Form.cs from Helper class, where you can bind all these properties with Form controls like text and Label controls.

In this way your UI and DB layer will be decoupled and form will not have any reference of DB.

Comment: OKay thanks for the help. How would this be implemented as when trying to put this into a new class the properties on the form e.g txtDescription cannot be accessed form a seperate class as they "do not exist "there .

Comment: Your SetResponse method from Helper class should return Modal class with all properties like description, color, Manufacture etc..

So, you can return Modal class with all properties in Form.cs where you can bind all properties with Form controls like text and Label controls.

In this way your UI and DB layer will be decoupled and form will not have any reference of DB. - updated same in answer for better readability.